# Como formatear una fecha y colocar puntos decimales en Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Tengo una consulta la cual obtiene campos tipo Date y campos tipo number

El resultado de esta consulta lo coloco en un archivo de excel y lo que hace es que NO muestra los campos de fecha con formato DD/MM/YYYY y tampoco muestra los campos de tipo number con decimales, trate de convertirlos con `to_char` pero al mostrarlos en el excel salen "null" los campos

```
SELECT F.ID, F.NOMBRE, TO_CHAR(F.FECHA_INI,'DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_CHAR(F.FECHA_REGISTRO,'DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_CHAR(F.FECHA.CARGA,'DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_CHAR(F.IMPORTE_UNO,'fm9990.00'), TO_CHAR(F.IMPORTE_DOS,'fm9990.00')
FROM FACTURA F
WHERE (?1 IS NULL OR  F.ID =?1)
AND F.FECHA_INI &gt;= TO_DATE(?2 'DD/MM/YYYY')
AND F.FECHA_INI &lt;= TO_DATE(?3 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

porque salen null al mostrarlos en el documento?

que me hace fata o esta mal?
También probé  `TO_DATE`  para la fecha y la muestra null

Este es código del método que utilizó para descargar el archivo con la consulta

```
if(factList !=null) {
    response.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/csv");
    response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=archivo.csv");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.write("columna1,columna2,columna3");
    out.write("\n");
    for(String factu: factList){
        out.write(factu.toCSVRepresentation()); 
        out.write("\n"); 
    } 
    out.flush(); 
    out.close(); 
}else{ 
    log.info("Esta vacio"); 
} 
}catch(ControlException e){ throw new ControlException("Error", e); } }
```

Comment: Como es que lo mandas al excel?

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta agregando el metido que tengo para mandarlo a Excel,bueno a .csv

Comment: y en el CSV estan bien los datos? puede ser un problema del excel en particular...

Comment: Si, Si les quito los to_char si pinta los campos pero no como quiero que salgan, con los puntos decimales y el formato de la fecha

Comment: Pero el problema es excel? puro de excel? probaste con otro excel? con otra configuracion? muchas veces vas a tener ese problema.. probaste una vez importado cambiar vos la configuracion de los campos en excel? por eso te pregunta, si el CSV estaba correcto.

Comment: Lo abrí con un txt  y también sale null  los campos, si estoy empleando bien los to_char?

Answer (score 0):

Porque no intentar generar tu archivo CSV desde el mismo oracle en un procedimiento almacenado, y para ver que se  genero correctamente puedes abrir tu csv con un notepad++

```
        --------------
        -- Cabecera
        --------------
        cursor cabecera is
        SELECT F.ID l1, F.NOMBRE l2, TO_CHAR(F.FECHA_INI,'DD/MM/YYYY') l3, TO_CHAR(F.FECHA_REGISTRO,'DD/MM/YYYY') l4, TO_CHAR(F.FECHA.CARGA,'DD/MM/YYYY') l5, TO_CHAR(F.IMPORTE_UNO,'fm9990.00') l6, TO_CHAR(F.IMPORTE_DOS,'fm9990.00') l7
        FROM FACTURA F
        WHERE (?1 IS NULL OR  F.ID =?1)
        AND F.FECHA_INI &gt;= TO_DATE(?2 'DD/MM/YYYY')
        AND F.FECHA_INI &lt;= TO_DATE(?3 'DD/MM/YYYY');

        --Recorres el cursor y vas generando linea por linea tu csv
        For i in cabecera loop
            nombre_archivo:='NombreArchivo||'.csv';
            v_archivo := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('RutaGuarda Archivo', nombre_archivo, 'W');  
                utl_file.putf(v_archivo,convert(i.l1||separador||'\n', 'AL32UTF8', 'WE8ISO8859P15'));
                utl_file.putf(v_archivo,convert(i.l2||separador||'\n', 'AL32UTF8', 'WE8ISO8859P15'));
                utl_file.putf(v_archivo,convert(i.l3||separador||'\n', 'AL32UTF8', 'WE8ISO8859P15'));
                utl_file.putf(v_archivo,convert(i.l4||separador||'\n', 'AL32UTF8', 'WE8ISO8859P15'));
                utl_file.putf(v_archivo,convert(i.l5||separador||'\n', 'AL32UTF8', 'WE8ISO8859P15'));
                utl_file.putf(v_archivo,convert(i.l6||separador||'\n', 'AL32UTF8', 'WE8ISO8859P15'));    
                utl_file.putf(v_archivo,convert(i.l7||separador||'\n', 'AL32UTF8', 'WE8ISO8859P15'));    
                utl_file.FCLOSE(v_archivo); --Cerrando el archivo
         end loop;
```